# Unable to set parent for Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.MessageBox.Show

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, messagebox, wpftoolkit

In my project the `Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit` is used.

I'm using MVVM i have a `MainView.xaml` and all other views are `UserControl`s 
I'm trying to show a message box from the code behind of my `UserControl` the message dialog parent is not set to it.

I will invoke dialog message when my `viewmode`l requires.

UserControl.Xaml.cs

```
   private void DialogMessageRecieved(DialogMessage dialMessage)
    {
        switch (dialMessage.Caption)
        {

            case "Warning":
                Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.MessageBox.Show(App.Current.MainWindow, dialMessage.Content, "Warning", dialMessage.Button, dialMessage.Icon);

                //i noticed that if i use native message box it works, 
               //by my app fully is implemented by Xceed

                 MessageBox.Show(App.Current.MainWindow,
                dialMessage.Content, "Warning", dialMessage.Button, dialMessage.Icon);
                    break;

        }
    }
```

When a message box is shown, user switch to another app and come back the application the message box is hidden , **it will only be shown after i press `ALT + TAB`**

[Tried this Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18660256/application-mainwindow-is-null-in-wpf-using-caliburn-micro)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Fixed issue by downgrading toolkit to Extended.Wpf.Toolkit -Version 2.3.0

There was issue Since v2.4, for the toolkit "the `MessageBox` owner is not applied".

[See the issue](https://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/workitem/21777)